# How to stop programmatically a Youtube video embedded inside UIWebView xcode

Tags: xcode, webview

I have an app developed in XCode6.1 for iPad

there I have a UIWebView with an embeded video this is the code:

```
[self.webView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
    [self.webView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];

    NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                           <html>\
                           <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                           <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>\
                           <script type='text/javascript'>\
                           function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\
                           {\
                           ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})\
                           }\
                           function onPlayerReady(a)\
                           { \
                           a.target.playVideo(); \
                           }\
                           </script>\
                           <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%f' height='%f' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>\
                           </body>\
                           </html>", self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height, @"JW5meKfy3fY"];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

but if I switch to another ViewController, the player stills playing the video, and I want it to stop, how to do that???

Answer (score 0):

iOS Helper Library from Google Developing site helped me a lot.
Quite simple!

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

```
    - (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
      [self.playerView playVideo];
    }

    - (IBAction)stopVideo:(id)sender {
      [self.playerView stopVideo];
    }
```